Average customer value
I have a table with customer purchase data.
|customer | month | Purchase amount | number of days shopped |
|A        |  jan  |     200         | 5|
|A        | feb   |        250      | 7|
| A        |march  |       330       | 8 |
| B        | jan   |      700        |15 |
|B        |feb    |      890        |25  |
| B        |  march|      310        |10  |
I am calculating the average purchase amount per day
(200 + 250 + 330 + 700 + 890 + 310)/ ( 5 + 7 + 8 + 15 + 25 + 10) = 38.28
But if I calculate the average purchase amount per day per customer, then
customer A = (200 + 250 + 330) / ( 5 + 7 + 8 ) = 39
Customer B = ( 700 + 890 + 310 ) / ( 15 + 25 + 10 ) = 38
(38 + 39 ) / 2 = 38.5
My question is why the averages are different in the two cases. Also, as a business, how can I understand the averages above? For example, what is the average amount a customer purchases every time he visits the shop? Is it 38.2 or 38.5?

Observe that the daily consumption average of consumers A and B (together) can be written as
\begin{align}
m&=\frac{200 + 250 + 330 + 700 + 890 + 310}{ 5 + 7 + 8 + 15 + 25 + 10}\\
&=
\frac{200 + 250 + 330}{ 5 + 7 + 8}\frac{ 5 + 7 + 8}{5 + 7 + 8 + 15 + 25 + 10} + \frac{700 + 890 + 310}{15 + 25 + 10}\frac{15 + 25 + 10}{5 + 7 + 8 + 15 + 25 + 10}\\
&=39\times 0.2857143 + 38\times 0.7142857
\end{align}
Thiat is, $m$ is the weighted avargage of the consumption average of A and B. The reason that the weighted average reflects better the satiation (compared to the arithmetic average of consumptions means of A and B) is that consumer B consumes, or rather, purchases for longer time  than A.
